# Different languages for different localizations

Tags: android, localization, multilingual

I am developing an application, that has both English and Russian language. I want my application to be in Russian for countries of former USSR and English for other countries.

The solution I was thinking about: to put the same files as in values-ru folder into values-xx localizations folders, where I want Russian to be the default language. The same thing to do with English: to copy files from values-en to values-xx (here values-xx are localization folders of those countries, where I want English to set as default language).

I doubt, that this is a correct solution. Is there a better and shorter solution for my task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `values` (with no county specifier) folder to place your resources in English; this will be your default language configuration. Then you can add Russian resources to the specific countries you want (i.e. the ex-USSR countries) like you say.

Comment: It's inconviniet for me to copy Russian localization to all the former USSR countries folders, because I'll have troubles if I want to edit some strings in Russian variant. It means, that I'll need to copy it to all those folders again.

Comment: What happens of you just put the russian strings.xml just in the values-ru folder? What is the default language configuration of phones in ex USSR countries? Russian?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can copy only string.xml from "values-ru" folder. Other localization automatically take strings from default "values" folder. You don't need to copy English version.